# Arabic Site proposal needs your support

Tags: discussion, support

I am hoping that many users of the LL community would be interested in the Arabic site proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language

Please support this proposal by following it, voting existing example questions and posting new ones.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it has been overtaken by events.

Answer (score 2):

The proposal has been closed.

> Arabic has repeatedly failed at garnering the community required to run a site. It is not appropriate to continue proposing this site here without having an established community already available to help it succeed. See [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0) – animuson♦